# Tweet to usernames from a Google Sheet with Zapier

Tags: twitter, zapier

I have collected a list of Twitter usernames and automatically created a `.csv` (Google Sheet). I created a zap to take the usernames and create individual messages. However even if I insert the @symbol, it doesn't show when I pull the username and post the tweet via Zapier. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Zapier disabled the ability to inject the @ sign in a Twitter integration from Google Sheets or from any other source for that matter (i tried it unsuccessfully with Zapier code as well). My hunch is this was done to the request of Twitter since it makes it damn easy to create really aggressive twitter bots this way.